# Gitlab-CI multi runner start docker container, scripts now work

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, executor

runner had been started docker container, the `config.toml` is:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "spring-boot-scripts"
  url = "http://xxxxx.com/ci"
  token = "xxxxxx"
  executor = "docker"
  builds_dir  = "/tmp/builds"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "spring-boot-demo:ci"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = true
    volumes = ["/cache"]
  [runners.cache]
    Insecure = false
```

and `.gitlab-ci.yml` is:

```
image: spring-boot-demo:ci
stages:
  - build

before_scipts:
  - mkdir /tmp/before_scripts
  - echo "============before_scripts========="

job1:
  stage: build
  script:
  - sh /home/admin/spring-boot-demo-application/bin/entrypoint.sh

after_scipts:
  - mkdir /tmp/after_scripts
  - echo "============after_scripts========="
```

gitlab's output like this,and building task cannot been stopped until cancelled:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.4.2 (bcc1794)
Using Docker executor with image spring-boot-demo:ci ...
Pulling docker image spring-boot-demo:ci ...
WARNING: Cannot pull the latest version of image spring-boot-demo:ci : Error: image library/spring-boot-demo:ci not found
WARNING: Locally found image will be used instead.
Running on runner-278e2660-project-114610-concurrent-0 via 6ca6af37d681...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/tmp/builds/spring-boot/startup-scripts'...
Checking out b58711bc as debug...
```

Now questions is:
if the before_scripts/script/after_scripts would been exec in container,why i can not find the directory /tmp/before_scripts,/tmp/after_scripts and jobs's script not work in container

Comment: 1. The scripts run inside the container. 2. You'll need to be more specific about what you expect to see and what isn't working. Gitlab shows the output of the build jobs so you can usually see clearly what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for your reply . if this scripts run inside the container, why can i not find the directory /tmp/before_scripts in the container , and entrypoint.sh had not been exec .

Comment: the building task result like this : 'Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.4.2 (bcc1794)
Using Docker executor with image spring-boot-demo:ci ...
Pulling docker image spring-boot-demo:ci ...
WARNING: Cannot pull the latest version of image spring-boot-demo:ci : Error: image library/spring-boot-demo:ci not found
WARNING: Locally found image will be used instead.
Running on runner-278e2660-project-114610-concurrent-0 via 6ca6af37d681...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/tmp/builds/spring-boot/startup-scripts'...
Checking out b58711bc as debug...'

Comment: Please put that information into the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find the folders because the jobs are not running. You have misspelled "script" in both the before_script and after_script jobs. Also, note that the correct job is not plural and does not have the 's' at the end.

[GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#before_script)